# Wondering if anyone knows the rule name for this square observation?

Tags: terminology, roots, recreational-mathematics, square-numbers

What is the name or rule for this observation on squares that I've explained below?

If you're at a number, say 400 (m^2)  which is a square of 20 (m), and you want to find the square of 25, that is 5 (n) numbers ahead. The square of 25 will be (2 * m * n) + n^2 ahead of m^2.

(25)^2 = 400 + 2 * 20 * 5 + 5^2 = 400 + 200 + 25 = 625

Another example: if you're at a number, say 121 (m^2)  which is a square of 11 (m), and you want to find the square of 15, that is 4 (n) numbers ahead.

(15)^2 = 121 + 2 * 11 * 4 + )^2 = 121 + 88 + 16 = 225

This observation will work very well within an algorithm/program where you need to efficiently brute force to find the decimal/float square root of any number, by finding the integer/whole-number square roots of the original number multiplied by powers of 100 in every iteration.

Comment: $(m+n)^2 = m^2 + 2mn + n^2$ is a well established identity if I'm not wrong.

Comment: It is a binomial theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

Comment: A useful rule : If you want to square a natural number ending with $5$ you can mutiply the part before the $5$ with "this part + 1" and add the digits $25$.

Comment: It generalizes to higher powers, with the coefficients coming from Pascal's Triangle.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Here is another $$m^2=(m-n)(m+m)+n^2.$$